# Multiple sums with joins in 1 query

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I am having a lot of problems with this query I am using. It seems that it is not counting the rows properly, and it is missing a lot.

Basically, I have 2 tables being utilized here. One is for `leads`, and the other is for `assignments`. Each lead can be assigned multiple times, therefore it can have multiple rows in the `assignments` table. The `dealerships` table is simply used to make sure it does not count the rows for certain dealers.

All I want to do here is count the number of leads that came from each website and break it down by day, week, month, etc.

Here are the structures of each table used in the query:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `assignments`
--

CREATE TABLE `assignments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_dealership` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lead` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_assigned` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `make` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_reassign` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'no',
  `manual_or_auto` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'N/A',
  `assigned_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'N/A',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `id_dealership` (`id_dealership`),
  KEY `date_assigned` (`date_assigned`),
  KEY `id_lead` (`id_lead`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26987 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `dealerships`
--

CREATE TABLE `dealerships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `province` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `email_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Car Lead',
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `leads` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `low_notif` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reassign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reassign_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salesman` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=190 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `leads`
--

CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_inf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name_first` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_last` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone_home` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone_cell` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone_work` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `province` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rentorown` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_months` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_years` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `monthly_income` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bankruptcy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tradein` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cosign` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `monthly_payment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `residence_years` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `residence_months` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `time_to_call` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `referrer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `source` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `id_infusionsoft` (`id_infusionsoft`),
  KEY `date_added` (`date_added`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22488 ;
```

Here is the query I am using:

```
select 
l.website,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_day,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_yesterday,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 2 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_2_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 3 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_3_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 4 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_4_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 5 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_5_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 6 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_6_days,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now() - interval 7 day, '%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_7_days,
sum(case when YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added))) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) AS c_week, 
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_month,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 1 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_last_month,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 2 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_2_months,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 3 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_3_months,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 4 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_4_months,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 5 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_5_months,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y-%m')= date_format(now() - interval 6 month, '%Y-%m') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_6_months,
sum(case when date_format(from_unixtime(COALESCE(a.date_assigned, l.date_added)), '%Y')= date_format(now(), '%Y') then 1 else 0 end) AS c_year  
from `leads` as l
left join `assignments` as a on (a.id_lead = l.id)
left join `dealerships` as d on (d.id = a.id_dealership)
where a.is_reassign='no' and a.id_dealership not in ('65', '77', '89', '138', '175', '177')
group by l.website
order by l.website asc
```

One thing to note, is that sometimes the `date_added` field is missing from the `leads` table for a lead, but `date_assigned` is present for the `assignments` of the lead and vice versa.

Why is my query not working properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're combining the operation of aggregating by date with the operation of pivoting.  Maybe you should debug your aggregating first, and then pivot. I *think* you're counting rows in your `sum(case(` expressions. Often counting rows on LEFT JOINs overcounts. Here's some information on aggregating by date. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Comment: could you give me an example of how you would write this query?